# Heroku db:push doesnt work. Says it needs taps installed even after taps has been installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I can't seem to get heroku to db:push, even though I have installed taps. It doesnt seem to believe me. I also checked and found a folder here: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.2.23/

> UM4345s-MacBook-Pro:photosite **$ sudo gem install taps**
>   Password:
>   Successfully installed rack-1.1.0
>   Successfully installed sinatra-0.9.2
>   Successfully installed thor-0.9.9
>   Successfully installed
>   rest-client-1.2.0 Successfully
>   installed sequel-3.0.0 Successfully
>   installed taps-0.2.23 6 gems installed
>   Installing ri documentation for
>   rack-1.1.0... Installing ri
>   documentation for sinatra-0.9.2...
>   Installing ri documentation for
>   thor-0.9.9... Installing ri
>   documentation for rest-client-1.2.0...
>   Installing ri documentation for
>   sequel-3.0.0... Installing ri
>   documentation for taps-0.2.23...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for
>   rack-1.1.0... Installing RDoc
>   documentation for sinatra-0.9.2...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for
>   thor-0.9.9... Installing RDoc
>   documentation for rest-client-1.2.0...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for
>   sequel-3.0.0... Installing RDoc
>   documentation for taps-0.2.23...
>   UM4345s-MacBook-Pro:photosite **$heroku db:push**
>   Install the Taps gem
>   to use db commands. On most systems
>   this will be: sudo gem install taps
>   UM4345s-MacBook-Pro:photosite **$ sudo gem install taps**
>   Password: Successfully installed
>   taps-0.2.23 1 gem installed Installing
>   ri documentation for taps-0.2.23...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for
>   taps-0.2.23...
>   UM4345s-MacBook-Pro:photosite$ **$heroku db:push**
>   Install the Taps gem
>   to use db commands. On most systems
>   this will be: sudo gem install taps

Comment: I have this problem as well - on ubuntu. It's rather sad that heroku offers no other way of getting data into your db (that I can tell) and that this method is so unreliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be fixed by upgrading your heroku gem with

```
gem update heroku
```

You might need a sudo as well depending on your environment.

Comment: Worked for me.  Any heroku strangeness starts with this :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the 'gem' for the current user the same as the run that's run from sudo?  I've had a problem with that when using REE or ruby installed from macports.  Quick check to compare:

```
which gem
sudo which gem

gem list | grep tap
sudo gem list | grep tap
```

It might be worth a try to purge both the taps and heroku gem and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RVM?  If so it's easy to be using the wrong gemset and not know it.